# Create a table with SQL from Query result in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a new table from a query result in SSMS

I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
(SELECT * FROM table1
 WHERE code = 'x'
 ORDER BY code;)
```

However I am getting an error telling me:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: You're looking for INTO   ...  Select * Into table2 FROM table1 WHERE code = 'x' ORDER BY code

Comment: MS SQL server, sorry I'm new to this did not know they were different

Comment: Remove the parentheses?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thank you that worked!

Comment: You appear to be using mysql syntax in mssql. mssql does not have create table as select. - one of the many differences between the two dialexts.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have the answer from @JohnCappelletti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM table1
WHERE code = 'x'
ORDER BY code;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I applied as provided by John Capelleti earlier above! Thanks!