# How to create a table with a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server and I have written some custom query and got the result. Now I want to save the result into a new table. How can I do that? Below is my SQL query. I want to store the result data into a new table.

```
SELECT  
    Name, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Total,
    IIF(Name = '', '0', '100') AS Vendor_Recognition,
    IIF(InvoiceNumber = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceNumber_Recognition,
    IIF(InvoiceDate = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceDate_Recognition,
    IIF(Total = '', '0', '100') AS Total_Recognition
FROM 
    Invoice
```

Comment: @KoushikRoy: this is **not** supported in T-SQL / SQL Server. See the answer by Tyron down below as to how to do it in SQL Server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a table with SQL from Query result in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503126/create-a-table-with-sql-from-query-result-in-ssms)

Comment: sorry, my bad. dint notice the tag. deleting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

What about a simple SELECT...INTO?

```
SELECT  Name, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Total,
        IIF(Name = '', '0', '100') AS Vendor_Recognition,
        IIF(InvoiceNumber = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceNumber_Recognition,
        IIF(InvoiceDate = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceDate_Recognition,
        IIF(Total = '', '0', '100') AS Total_Recognition
    INTO MyNewTable
    FROM Invoice
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT... INTO.. syntax.

```
SELECT  
    Name, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Total,
    IIF(Name = '', '0', '100') AS Vendor_Recognition,
    IIF(InvoiceNumber = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceNumber_Recognition,
    IIF(InvoiceDate = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceDate_Recognition,
    IIF(Total = '', '0', '100') AS Total_Recognition
INTO MyNewTable
FROM 
    Invoice
```

also make sure you provide enough length in case if you want to insert more queries in same table

```
SELECT  
        Name, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Total,
        IIF(Name = '', '0', '100') AS Vendor_Recognition,
        IIF(InvoiceNumber = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceNumber_Recognition,
        IIF(InvoiceDate = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceDate_Recognition,
        cast(IIF(Total = '', '0', '100')) as Decimal(10,2) AS Total_Recognition  -- as this way you can define data type for MyNewTable
    INTO MyNewTable
    FROM 
        Invoice
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    Name, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Total,
    IIF(Name = '', '0', '100') AS Vendor_Recognition,
    IIF(InvoiceNumber = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceNumber_Recognition,
    IIF(InvoiceDate = '', '0', '100') AS InvoiceDate_Recognition,
    IIF(Total = '', '0', '100') AS Total_Recognition
INTO MyInvoice
FROM 
    Invoice
```

I have written query to store your result in table named 'MyInvoice'. Please note below query is not re-runnable and if you want to make it re-runnable you have to drop the table first and then execute the query given above

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to insert data from an existing table is Insert Into:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

You can find elaborting information here:
[SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

PS: Wow just saw CREATE TABLE new_table
AS (SELECT * FROM old_table); in a comment. That is syntax i did not know yet. Thank you [Create Table (with as explaination)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable AS
SELECT customername, contactname
FROM customers;
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ..... ` is **not** supported in T-SQL/SQL Server. You need to use `SELECT (list of columns) INTO NewTableName FROM .....` instead

Answer (score -1):

I think creating the table first and then inserting the result will be a good idea as it will give us an option to define indexes at the time of table creation which will be helpful in performance and catching. Thoughts?